# How to view all layer sizes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, layers

I have received a design as a .psd and a .png file, but the designer has not added the sizes of each header, image, padding, etc.

Is there a way to quickly and efficiently see the size of each object / section?

One small detail, I do not have Photoshop, and I do not wish to install it. I prefer a solution that does not require Photoshop.

Comment: No. Not really. Even opening psds outside of photoshop is kind of difficult if you want to retain layers. There are a few photoshop plugins that give you dimensions of each layer relatively automatically. Few other things come to mind. If we are talking about a website design or something, [Avocode](http://avocode.com/) supports psds. Then there are also a few measuring apps for mac, which are not exactly automatic or anything, but can be pretty useful: [Pixel Winch](http://bit.ly/1JpgNj1), [SnapRuler](http://bit.ly/1Lw2lfc),  [xScope](http://bit.ly/1V9dCbo), [PixFit](http://bit.ly/1OukP1j)

Comment: Also if they can share the PSD with you over Adobe Cloud, then you can use the online tools to make measurements and to generate the CSS directly from their site

Comment: @Joonas you should make that an answer